# Are there any desktop clients for Soundcloud?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone know a good desktop client for Soundcloud (are there any)?
If not complete feature support then at least a player which can integrate and play Soundcloud account songs.

I found [jamcloud](http://jamcloud.com/), but it runs using Adobe AIR and Adobe AIR is no longer supported for Linux, furthermore if possible I want to avoid using Wine to run Adobe AIR.

Comment: There is [CloudDeck](http://clouddeck.net/) which supports Linux, however that too uses Adobe Air

Comment: I'll try it but obviously will still be waiting for native client Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried running the [soundcloud mobile site](http://m.soundcloud.com/) as a pinned desktop application in Chrome etc ?

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this question. From the fact that there is no accepted answer, can I deduce that none of the proposed solutions ultimately worked? Either way, if you or anyone else has a solution, I'd still be interested.

Answer (score 18):

You can try [Tomahawk](http://www.tomahawk-player.org/). There exists a [Soundcloud Content Resolver](http://www.tomahawk-player.org/resolvers.html). Tomahawk is [abandoned](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/tomahawk-music-player-essentially-abandoned).

[image: tomahawk soundcloud resolver]

[image: tomahawk soundcloud playing track screenshot]

You could install Tomahawk from a [PPA for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~tomahawk/+archive/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomahawk/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomahawk
```

---

[Rhythmbox](http://sysads.co.uk/2015/04/rhythmbox-3-2-0-released-with-soundcloud-plugin-support/) has also a [Soundcloud plugin](https://github.com/GNOME/rhythmbox/tree/master/plugins/soundcloud)

[image: Rhythmbox with Soundcloud plugin screenshot]

---

For the [Nuvola Player](http://nuvolaplayer.fenryxo.cz/home.html) exists a [feature request for soundcloud integration](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nuvola-player/+bug/1010111). You could mark the *"bug"* so that is affecting you.

---

[Soundnode](http://www.soundnodeapp.com/) - An [opensource](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app) SoundCloud app for desktop

[image: Soundnode image]

---

[Harmony](http://getharmony.xyz/) - An [opensource](https://github.com/vincelwt/harmony) app for desktop, which supports Soundcloud, Spotify etc.

[image: Harmony image]

---

[Cumulus](https://gillesdemey.github.io/Cumulus/) - An [opensource](https://github.com/gillesdemey/Cumulus) SoundCloud player that lives in your menubar.

[image: Cumulus image]

---

[Auryo](https://auryo.com/) - An [opensource](https://github.com/Superjo149/auryo/) SoundCloud client for your desktop.

[image: Auryo image]

Comment: Hey Tomahawk is pretty awesome (though I didn't find a way to sign in to my soundcloud account) Neither did I saw so many options as in screen shot (maybe in newer version they removed few options). For now creating web app with frogger seems to be working (for sign in). I will read about Tomahawk some more I'm liking the concept a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the overview. Rhythmbox works decently in Gnome, although it's very basic (e.g. you can't arrange tracks into playlists..)
I found Auryo (https://auryo.com/) which looks quite promising, but there are currently some issues due to some new Soundcloud APIs and the developer said on his Twitter account that is rewriting the software.

Answer (score 6):

You could try fogger to create a Webapp for the unity desktop:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/fogger-aims-to-bring-integrated-web-apps-to-ubuntu

You can write userspace scripts that allow nice integration with the desktop.  There's already pre-packaged scripts available for Facebook and Wunderlist.
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/?s=fogger

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try in a day or 2 and update here :)

Comment: This works properly, Thanks. I liked Tomahawk more though (if I don't find a way to sign in to Tomahawk, this is best possible solution)

Answer (score 4):

[Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/) supports Soundcloud since version 1.1 (October 2012)

Comment: I tried it. When I click the Soundcloud Login button in the app, it takes me to a page on soundcloud.com with a message like "This client provider is not supported". I could not get it to play anything from Soundcloud.

Comment: It's a reported [issue](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/5538).

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, [Soundnode App](http://www.soundnodeapp.com) now support Linux besides Mac and Windows.

Comment: It might be me, but the install script is not working (even when i manually set the OS), and what was in the zip-file is broken for me

Answer (score 3):

There's a command line interface program written in Ruby: http://soundcli.elephly.net/

It's able to connect to your SoundCloud account and stream your own music, playlist, favs. And, of course, you can play other's music.

> **Thing is:** you can't browse. You have to specify the song you want to play URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firefox app for Soundcloud, which partly integrate into your environment.

It is fairly limited (no way to play your stream for the moment, no sound menu integration - it must be that it was developed for phones and features are missing on the desktop) but at least it is lightweight and you can lock it to the launcher.

It is available on the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/soundcloud?src=search).

Answer (score 0):

In chrome browser you can open sound cloud page, when go to options (3 wertical lines in the corner), select "More tools" > "Create application shortcut..". You will get shortcut tha opens directly sound cloud.
I use it that way. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to play Sountdrack tracks in VLC.
I copied [this SoundCloud Plugin](https://gist.github.com/MarcuzD/e327fe20be054efc9b5f) into `/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/`.
Then I just pasted the URL in Media->Open Network Stream. It worked

I haven't tried it without the plugin.

It uses much less CPU than the browser, but when it reaches the end of the track, it just stops. I couldn't get this particular setup to load playlists. If I paste the URL for a playlist, it just plays the first song.