# Is there any Soundcloud desktop client except Tomahawk?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a Soundcloud desktop client. I found this post quite relevant, and somebody has suggeted Tomahawk, but the post is pretty old:
[Are there any desktop clients for Soundcloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92592/are-there-any-desktop-clients-for-soundcloud/322382#322382)

Is there any great desktop client to browse your sets, listen to your tracks, search for and listen to new tracks, create sets, upload your tracks, and follow people all from inside the client?

Comment: By the way, Tomahawk is buggy. It doesn't play any track. When you click on a track to play it back, it gets loaded in the player like it's ready to be played, but it doesn't get played, even if you click on the play button again.

Comment: I'm wondering why is this question marked as duplicate? Before posting this question, I asked this question as an answer to the previous question for better answers because answers were not satisfying and the question was pretty old and I thought there might be new social players for this purpose, but a moderator suggested in a private message asking the question as a new question. Then I posted this question, and then some moderators marked it as duplicate. Isn't something wrong?